# Displaying outputs of a vector into a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

Using Matlab, I will like to display the difference between columns 1 and 3, columns 2 and 3, columns 4 and 3 of the following 21x4 vector data and display the output in a 21x3 vector.

Please can anyone assist?

-48.0000  -46.0000  -38.0000  -39.0000

-51.0000  -49.3333  -41.5218  -48.0000

-49.0000  -51.6667  -44.0206  -49.0000

-55.0000  -53.3333  -45.9588  -49.0000

-56.0000  -54.3333  -47.5424  -52.0000

-52.0000  -53.6667  -48.8814  -52.0000

-53.0000  -51.0000  -50.0412  -48.0000

-48.0000  -51.6667  -51.0643  -48.0000

-54.0000  -52.0000  -51.9794  -48.0000

-54.0000  -52.6667  -52.8073  -50.0000

-50.0000  -52.3333  -53.5630  -50.0000

-53.0000  -54.3333  -54.2583  -50.0000

-60.0000  -54.6667  -54.9020  -51.0000

-51.0000  -54.0000  -55.5012  -51.0000

-51.0000  -51.6667  -56.0618  -51.0000

-53.0000  -52.3333  -56.5884  -51.0000

-53.0000  -55.6667  -57.0849  -53.0000

-61.0000  -58.6667  -57.5545  -53.0000

-62.0000  -61.0000  -58.0000  -60.0000

-60.0000  -60.0000  -58.4238  -58.0000

-58.0000  -59.6667  -58.8279  -58.0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, save your values into a variable, as:

```
var = [...
-48.0000 -46.0000 -38.0000 -39.0000
-51.0000 -49.3333 -41.5218 -48.0000
-49.0000 -51.6667 -44.0206 -49.0000
-55.0000 -53.3333 -45.9588 -49.0000
-56.0000 -54.3333 -47.5424 -52.0000
-52.0000 -53.6667 -48.8814 -52.0000
-53.0000 -51.0000 -50.0412 -48.0000
-48.0000 -51.6667 -51.0643 -48.0000
-54.0000 -52.0000 -51.9794 -48.0000
-54.0000 -52.6667 -52.8073 -50.0000
-50.0000 -52.3333 -53.5630 -50.0000
-53.0000 -54.3333 -54.2583 -50.0000
-60.0000 -54.6667 -54.9020 -51.0000
-51.0000 -54.0000 -55.5012 -51.0000
-51.0000 -51.6667 -56.0618 -51.0000
-53.0000 -52.3333 -56.5884 -51.0000
-53.0000 -55.6667 -57.0849 -53.0000
-61.0000 -58.6667 -57.5545 -53.0000
-62.0000 -61.0000 -58.0000 -60.0000
-60.0000 -60.0000 -58.4238 -58.0000
-58.0000 -59.6667 -58.8279 -58.0000 ];
```

Second, you can access the columns through the first parameter of var, and using the special character ":" to select all row values; that is:

var(:,1) will select all values in column 1.

```
var(:,1)-var(:,2)
```

will give you the difference between these two columns.

You can work out the rest.

Your ourput can more simply be displayed as:

```
output = [var(:,1)-var(:,3) var(:,2)-var(:,3) var(:,4)-var(:,3)]
```

Comment: `var(:,[1 2 4]) - var(:,3)` should do the same thing, right?

Comment: @beaker In Octave yes ;-)

Comment: In Matlab `bsxfun(@minus,var(:,[1 2 4]),var(:,3))` would do

Comment: Thanks. You guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

Difference between x-th column and y-th column can be achieved as following:

```
disp(myMatrix(:,x)-myMatrix(:,y));
```

The `disp()` function is actually just a print-on-screen function, the *core* of this code relies on what's inside the brackets of `myMatrix`: the colon operator `:` means *all of it* so by recalling that the first index in round brackets identifies rows whereas the second index identifies columns, saying `myMatrix(:,x)` means "return all the rows and the x-th column of myMatrix".

So in your specific case:

- difference between columns 1 and 3
- difference between columns 2 and 3
- difference between columns 4 and 3

can be achieved (respectively) as

```
myMatrix(:,1)-myMatrix(:,3)
myMatrix(:,2)-myMatrix(:,3)
myMatrix(:,4)-myMatrix(:,3)
```

where `myMatrix`, obviously, is your 21x4 matrix.

If you want to concatenate such values in a matrix, this can be easily done by simple array concatenation:

```
myOutput=[myMatrix(:,1)-myMatrix(:,3) , myMatrix(:,2)-myMatrix(:,3) , myMatrix(:,4)-myMatrix(:,3)];
```

in which every resulting column will be a column in `myOutput`. Finally then you can display the entire `myOutput` matrix thanks to the `disp()` command as well.

Comment: Thanks. You guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

To compute the difference with respect to a given column you can use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as follows:

```
x = [-48.0000 -46.0000 -38.0000 -39.0000
     -51.0000 -49.3333 -41.5218 -48.0000
     -49.0000 -51.6667 -44.0206 -49.0000
     -55.0000 -53.3333 -45.9588 -49.0000
     -56.0000 -54.3333 -47.5424 -52.0000]; %// data
c = 3; %// index of reference column
y = bsxfun(@minus, x(:, [1:c-1 c+1:end]), x(:,c));
```

which gives

```
y =
  -10.0000   -8.0000   -1.0000
   -9.4782   -7.8115   -6.4782
   -4.9794   -7.6461   -4.9794
   -9.0412   -7.3745   -3.0412
   -8.4576   -6.7909   -4.4576
```

Comment: Thanks. You guys are the best!